# Why isn't the png image centered within the parent div?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center a image within a container.

According to what I've understood, setting a container's `position` as "`relative`" that has a property of text-align set to center should
 center block-level elements vertically that has their `position`
 property set to `absolute`. However, why isn't this the case with my
 code?

```css
.first-container {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.mountain {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Playground</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="first-container">
    <img class="mountain" src="images/mountain.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="second-container">

  </div>
  <div class="third-container">

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I expected that the mountain image would be at the center of the first container that I set the background color to yellow for ease of distinction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `position: absolute` on an image in a container with `position: relative`, your image *is* at the center of your container. Or, more specifically, the *top-left pixel* of your image is as the center.

In order to center the image so that the center of the image is in the center of the containing element, you want to set a `margin-left` of negative half of the image's width. This can be seen in the following, with an image that's `100px` wide, with `margin-left: -50px`:

```css
.first-container {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.mountain {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="first-container">
  <img class="mountain" src="https://placehold.it/100" alt="">
</div>
```

And assuming you set the `width` on the image itself, you can actually make use of a combination of CSS variables and `calc()` in order to determine this margin, with `width: var(--image-width)` and `margin-left: calc(var(--image-width) / -2)` on the image.

```css
:root {
  --image-width: 100px;
}

.first-container {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.mountain {
  position: absolute;
  width: var(--image-width);
  margin-left: calc(var(--image-width) / -2);
}
```

```html
<div class="first-container">
  <img class="mountain" src="https://placehold.it/100" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

your code is right but has a little bit bug here, you need to set height property to some pixels then you can see the image. For example:

```
.first-container {
background-color: yellow;
height: 400px;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

added

```
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

to `.mountain`. Hope this helps you. Thanks

```css
.first-container {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.mountain {
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Playground</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="first-container">
    <img class="mountain"src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4e/Artesonraju3.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="second-container">

  </div>
  <div class="third-container">

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```